# SSL Issue, Logging in to website

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have this code to login to a server called Pinger TextFree for a bot I'm working on:

```
<?php
function sendRequest($url, $postorget, $fields = array(), $proxy)
{
    $cookie_file = "cookies.txt";

    //Initiate connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return the transfer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // allow https
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'); // random agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // automatically follow Location: headers (ie redirects)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // auto set the referer in the event of a redirect
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); // ibm likes to redirect a lot, make sure we dont get stuck in a loop
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file); // file to save cookies in
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file); // file to read cookies from
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 40); //timeout time for curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80); //port to connect to (default 80 obviously)

    //Check to see if a proxy is being used
    if(isset($proxy)){
        //Tell cURL you're using a proxy
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
        //Set the proxy
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
    }

    //Check if request is POST or GET
    if ($postorget == "post" OR $postorget == "POST")
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // use POST
        if (is_array($fields)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields)); // key => name gets turned into &key=name
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); // &key=name passed in
        }
    } else { 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); // use GET
    }

    $content = curl_exec($ch); // return html content
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch); // return transfer info
    $error = curl_error($ch);  // return any errors

    curl_close($ch);

    $request = array('content' => $content,
             'error' => $error,
         'info' => $info);

    return $request;            
}

//Login details
$username = "usernamehere";
$password = "passwordhere";

//GET the initial login page
$initFields = "";
$initOutput = sendRequest("http://www.pinger.com/tfw/?t=1360619019053", "GET", $initFields);

echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='400'>";
print_r($initOutput);
echo "</textarea>";

//Login to pinger
$loginFields = "{\"username\":\"".$username."\",\"password\":\"".$password."\",\"clientId\":\"textfree-in-flash-web-free-1360619009-8CA1C5C1-38ED-2E31-3248-CB367450A20F\"}";
$loginOutput = sendRequest("https://api.pinger.com/1.0/web/login", "POST", $loginFields);

echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='400'>";
print_r($loginOutput);
echo "</textarea>";

?>
```

For some reason every time I try to run this script all I get is "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.pinger.com:80"

What am I doing wrong here? I'll even specify SSL2 in the setop but it just hangs forever - I just can't get this to work!

Here is the app I'm trying to automate: http://www.pinger.com/tfw/

It's in flash but I'm using Fiddler to sniff the HTTP/HTTPS requests to automate them with cURL.

Any ideas from you guys?

Comment: HTTP uses port 443 by default, you're always using 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is *obviously* in the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80); //port to connect to (default 80 obviously)
```

HTTPS servers listen on port 443 by default. Simply deleting this line should be sufficient; curl will then figure out the port from the protocol in the URL.

Comment: Doesn't he also need to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to true? I suspect what's happening is that pinger receives the request on http and automatically tries to redirect it to https.

Comment: @mkaatman Nope, that doesn't explain the error message (a redirect would mean the port should be 443 in the message, not 80). VERIFYPEER just makes curl *check* the server certificate.

Comment: OK this seems to partially solve my problem so thank you! I still get "Unauthenticated client" but I think that's from the OAuth?

Comment: @MandatoryProgrammer yup, looks like that. If your efforts don't succeed, feel free to ask a new question for that problem.